why gradient scaling used in mix-precision training could lead to bigger Learning Rate in float32 model?
Background:
Gradient Scaling original is used in mix-precision training like (part of model weights are float16 and part of them are float 32), which its purpose is to reduce underflow of small gradients stored with float16.
Recently, I was doing some experiments and found some result confussing me. In the case of whole model with float32 weights, if I update the model with Gradient Scaling, I could use much bigger LR (Learning Rate) for convergence compared to don't use it.
Scaled version updating code excerpt:
loss_scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
loss_scaler.scale(loss).backward()
loss_scaler.unscale_(optimizer)
loss_scaler.step(optimizer)
loss_scaler.update()

unscaled version updating code excerpt:
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

Problem:
why would this happen? Should the scaled gradients be cancelled out tranformed to original gradients? What I expect is that thier LR should be the same for model training?
Here is the ChatGPT's explaination:
Even float32 could underflow, and the scale make these underflow gradients make contribute to the weights updating which make training more stable, so the lr could be bigger.
I wonder if this explaination is reasonable, cause the LR is much different. (1.5e-4 vs 1.5e-8)
